# How to send an object in react to another component using useNavigate

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to send an object from one react component to another. I have tried the exact same thing as here, [react-router-dom v6 useNavigate passing value to another component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64566405/react-router-dom-v6-usenavigate-passing-value-to-another-component), but it works only for Strings or Integers. If I have a more complex object, instead of receiving it, I receive Object:object. Is anything there that I'm missing?

Comment: Try sending the object, in string form, using JSON.stringify, and then parse it back into the JSON within the component, using JSON.parse

Comment: For objects you can also use simple state management tools like zustand (https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand)