# In React Router V6, can I still get RouteComponentProps (or access to history and location) in class components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

**Background**
I'm migrating from v4 to v6. Many of my pages are class components, not functional components, and I relied heavily on RouteComponentProps (written with Typescript):

```
export class UserDashboard extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps> {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.updateURL = buildURLUpdater(props.history, props.location, ...);
    console.log(props.user);
  }

  onChooseUser = (newUser) => {
    this.setState({
      user: newUser
    }, this.updateURL);
  }

  ...
}

<Switch>
  <Route path="/users">
    <Users focusUser={user} />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

**Question** I know that React Router V6 relies heavily on hooks, but I'm not sure how to get `location` or `history` in a class component. Is this still possible?

**Why** I wrote a handy function that I can run after every `setState` command that would automatically update the URL and insert a history item without having to navigate. This would be for when I want the current search text to show up in the URL bar as the user types. I used props.location and props.history to do that. So if I can't get route component props anymore, I need a way to grab the history and location object, or whatever its V6 equivalents are, in the constructor of a class.

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64566486/8690857 To update the queryString params you'd use the `useSearchParams` hook.

Comment: @DrewReese Maybe. I have to use a wrapper to grab the values from hooks and pass them on?

Comment: Yes, you have to user either a wrapper component and pass them along, or create a `withRouter` HOC replacement to do the same.