# get rowdata from syncfusion grid to another page on click of button

Tags: syncfusion

I have a syncfusion grid, in that i have multiple columns in the child grid and there is another column with a button, onclick of that button i want to go to another page which displays all the data from that row, any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

After validating your query, we could see that you are having button in your template column and when you click on this button you like to navigate to another page with respective row information. Based on your query, we have prepared a sample and achieved your requirement by using useLocation and useNavigate React hooks. Please refer the below code example, sample and video demo for more information.

```
function About() {
    let gridInstance;
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    
    function handleClick(args) { //button click of column template
        //pass the rowinformation to another componet
        const value = gridInstance.getRowInfo(args.target.closest('tr')).rowData;
        navigate('/Contact', {state: { data: value }});
    }
    function columnTemplate(props) {
        return(
            <div>
            <button type="button" onClick={handleClick.bind(props)}> Go Contact page </button>
            </div> 
        ) 
    }
    return (
        <div className='control-pane'>
            <div className='control-section'>
                
                <GridComponent ref={grid=>gridInstance=grid} dataSource={data.slice(0,5)} >
                    <ColumnsDirective>
                        <ColumnDirective field='OrderID' headerText='Order ID' width='120' textAlign='Right'></ColumnDirective>
                        <ColumnDirective field='CustomerID' headerText='Customer ID' width='150'></ColumnDirective>
                        <ColumnDirective field='OrderDate' headerText='Order Date' width='130' format='yMd' textAlign='Right' />
                        <ColumnDirective field='Freight' headerText='Freight' width='120' format='C2' textAlign='Right' />
                        <ColumnDirective field='ShipCountry' headerText='Ship Country' width='150'></ColumnDirective>
                        <ColumnDirective headerText='Template Column' template={columnTemplate} width='150'></ColumnDirective>
                    </ColumnsDirective>
                </GridComponent>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default About;
```

In ComponentB we have received the passed value and set as the Grid datasource.

```
const Contact =(props)=> {
    const location = useLocation();
    const dataObject = location.state.data; //received the data using useLocation()
    
    return (
        <div className='control-pane'>
            <div className='control-section'>
                <GridComponent dataSource={[dataObject]} >
                    <ColumnsDirective>
                    <ColumnDirective field='OrderID' headerText='Order ID' width='120' textAlign='Right'></ColumnDirective>
                        <ColumnDirective field='CustomerID' headerText='Customer ID' width='150'></ColumnDirective>
                        <ColumnDirective field='OrderDate' headerText='Order Date' width='130' format='yMd' textAlign='Right' />
                        <ColumnDirective field='Freight' headerText='Freight' width='120' format='C2' textAlign='Right' />
                        <ColumnDirective field='ShipCountry' headerText='Ship Country' width='150'></ColumnDirective>
                    </ColumnsDirective>
                </GridComponent>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Contact;
```

Sample: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bCJOe8OxecjlfjbUn5R1Vz2L1De5Ip2m/view?usp=drive_link

Video Demo: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_4ls8BaGzIGL6AMMC37Zzjt5iGDI6zIy/view?usp=drive_link

Also, please refer the below public general link for more information.

General link: [react-router-dom v6 useNavigate passing value to another component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64566405/react-router-dom-v6-usenavigate-passing-value-to-another-component)